# Sort array Angular 7 by number field on decreasing or increase order

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, rxjs, angular7

i need an help, 
i need to sort array by PendingQuantity field. I've negative and positive numbers.
So my code:

```
this.data.Products.sort(obj => obj.PendingQuantity);
```

So my array

```
"Products": [
            {
                "ProductCode": "MC30180",
                "Description": "Description_1",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
                "PendingQuantity": 20,
                "toBeScanned": true
            },
            {
                "ProductCode": "Name_2",
                "Description": "Description_2",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
                "PendingQuantity": -3,
                "toBeScanned": false
            },
            {
                "ProductCode": "Name_3",
                "Description": "Description_3",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
                "PendingQuantity": 25,
                "toBeScanned": false
            }
        ]
```

the order i want is:

```
"Products": [
                {
                    "ProductCode": "MC30180",
                    "Description": "Description_1",
                    "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
                    "PendingQuantity": -3,
                    "toBeScanned": true
                },
                {
                    "ProductCode": "Name_2",
                    "Description": "Description_2",
                    "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
                    "PendingQuantity": 25,
                    "toBeScanned": false
                },
                {
                    "ProductCode": "Name_3",
                    "Description": "Description_3",
                    "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
                    "PendingQuantity": 20,
                    "toBeScanned": false
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this for order asc `product = product.sort((a, b) => a.PendingQuantity - b.PendingQuantity);`

If you want to order by desc use `product = product.sort((a, b) => b.PendingQuantity - a.PendingQuantity);`

Update:

If you show custom order like -3, 25, 20, you can handle sorting condition.

```
product = product.sort((a, b) => { if (a.PendingQuantity < 0) {return -1; } if (b.PendingQuantity <0 ) {return 1;} return b.PendingQuantity - a.PendingQuantity });
```

```js
let product = [
            {
                "ProductCode": "MC30180",
                "Description": "Description_1",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
                "PendingQuantity": 20,
                "toBeScanned": true
            },
            {
                "ProductCode": "Name_2",
                "Description": "Description_2",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
                "PendingQuantity": -3,
                "toBeScanned": false
            },
            {
                "ProductCode": "Name_3",
                "Description": "Description_3",
                "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
                "PendingQuantity": 25,
                "toBeScanned": false
            }
        ];
        
        
product = product.sort((a, b) => a.PendingQuantity - b.PendingQuantity);
product = product.sort((a, b) => { if (a.PendingQuantity < 0) {return -1; } if (b.PendingQuantity <0 ) {return 1;} return b.PendingQuantity - a.PendingQuantity });

console.log(product);
```

Comment: I need to order like this: -3 first, 25 second, 20 third element, the negative it's handled in your example ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sort` function of `Array`

```
products.sort((a,b)=> a['PendingQuantity'] - b['PendingQuantity']);
```

Comment: The above will give you ascending order, if you want descending order, then try : `product.sort((a, b) => -(a.PendingQuantity - b.PendingQuantity));`

Comment: Sorrry but, you script works but the negativa number show on the end, there is a method to have -3, 25, 20 like a order ?